# XSCRON for scheduling a xsjob

Tags: cron, hana-xs

I need a XS Cron to schedule a job for every second Tuesday of every month.
I have a Cron which is "* * * tue 12 0 0"; it states that the job is scheduled for every month every tuesday to run at 12.
So Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea of XS. I hope below cron will work well as per your requirement.

You can validate on https://crontab.guru

"At every minute on every day-of-month from 8 through 14 and on Tuesday."

"* * 8-14 * TUE Your_script_path"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you help.
The cron that I am using to schedule my job for every months second Tuesday is 
"* * * 2.tue 12 0 0"

Regards,
Renita